# I want to add a WCF service to an already existing project but under Add Items I don't find WCF service in VS2010?

Tags: wcf

I am trying to add a WCF service in an already existing project using VS 2010. But when i right click on the project name and then Add Items , i could not find any WCF Service Template.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help someone. After Changing the Framework of my project i found WCF Service template under the Project.